# java_home command missing on OS X

Tags: macos, java

Mac OS X 10.8 does not include [`java_home(1)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/java_home.1.html). The Apple docs stop at 10.7.4, so I'm not sure what I should be using to set `JAVA_HOME` in a login script.

What are we supposed to use to set `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/libexec/java_home` is what the variable should be

Comment: Thanks Luke. For whatever reason, the Apple docs stop at 10.7.4 and `java_home` died at the command line. `/usr/libexec/java_home` worked as desired, though.